# How to take a complex equation from user through React JS UI?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I am making a project where I am selecting columns from multiple CSV files, performing mathematical calculations on their data, and generating a result file with that data in it.

Now the calculation is happening through a Python API which is using Pandas library to achieve this.

The problem is at the front end, I am not able to develop an approach where I can take inputs from user and form an equation which I can pass as a request to the python API and generate result (here, I do not want user to type equation manually in a simple input field).

Example of Expression is this:

> **((temp:Qty*2)+(Bank:Total_Trans_Amt*1/3)+(temp:Qty+Bank:Total_Trans_Amt))**

But to make it more understandable I modified the code to take input in this form:

> **sum(mul(temp:Qty,2),mul(Bank:Total_Trans_Amt,1/3),sum(temp:Qty,Bank:Total_Trans_Amt))**

which looks like calling functions with argument, so many people will be familiar. Now this equation is getting converted to the first one, and then operation is happening.

Here,

> **temp:Qty** is column named **Qty** from file **temp.csv**

> **Bank:Total_Trans_Amt** is column named **Total_Trans_Amt** from file **Bank.csv**

To give you a basic idea of how it's supposed to work is

1. Column names from different will be fetched into a Dropdown (in format like fileName:columnName ).
2. Operations will be listed into a different Dropdown (like Sum, mul etc).
3. User will select columns and operations from dropdowns and generate an equation which will be implemented by Python API

I am stuck on this for couple of weeks, So I am looking for solutions/suggestions, and all are welcome. My apologies if I asked/said anything wrong in this question.

Comment: Tangential: more people know math than programming. My approach would be to keep it as a simple equation and autocomplete the variables.

Comment: Well, any form of the equation will work for me, do you have any suggestions on how to achieve it using dropdowns?

Comment: Isn’t it just inserting the drop-down value into a text box? Or having expression components, each of which have their own drop downs etc? There are many approaches; maybe search for “expression builder” or “gui expression builder”. They’re fun to write, though.